# Manifest not reach in activity

Tags: kotlin

I try to call **MainFest** in activity but it's not show in here

```
fun select(view: View) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Mainfest))
    }
```

Comment: Hi @FaridMuhmmad, welcome to Stack Overflow, please attach your class definition for `Mainfest` so we know what's going on.

Comment: I guess you mean `android.Manifest`